# document.write doesn't work in Chrome on images opened in new tabs

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

In Chrome, open an image by selecting "Open image in new tab" from the context menu. Open the console in the newly opened tab and run the following code:

```
document.open();
document.write("foo");
document.close();
```

Instead of a document with only the text "foo" in it, the result is, well, nothing at all. I first noticed this when jQuery failed to load, citing the document variable being undefined as the reason. The code works as expected in all other pages.

I also tried running the same thing in Firefox (except it was "View image") and it worked as expected, which leads me to believe this is specific to Chrome.

I have also noticed that, when you open an image in Firefox, the type of the document object isn't HTMLDocument, but ImageDocument. I have tried to find whether Chrome does something similar, but to no avail.

I'm writing a Chrome extension which also needs to stop all loaded Javascript and insert `<!DOCTYPE html>` when necessary, so editing `document.innerHTML` isn't an option.

Comment: I find the intention clearer with document.open() called first.

Comment: That's because there is no document object. Most browsers don't bother create a DOM when the response header indicates that an image or other non HTML document is being loaded. This is because there is no need - no HTML to parse and no JavaScript to execute

Comment: @RandomUser If you inspect the image opened in a new tab, you can see it's an `<img>` element with the appropriate `src`attribute and it can be manipulated like any other page.